# Preliminary Chapters Not Showing Up in Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I am creating a larger overall project with this document. The issue I am having is that the list of figures and tables does not show up as sections in the table of contents at all or with the Roman Numerals.

**Package load**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[width=150mm,top=35mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

**Main Code**

Below is the code being used for the `main.tex` file.

```
\title{sample}
\author{} 
\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} 

\input{titlepage}

\input{abstract}

\tableofcontents


\listoffigures
\listoftables

\doublespacing


%\chapter{Acknowledgements}  
%\input{chapters/Acknowledgements}

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\input{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Overview}
\input{chapters/chapter02}

\chapter{Theory}
\input{chapters/chapter03}

\chapter{Methodology}
\input{chapters/chapter04}

\chapter{Conclusion}
\input{chapters/conclusion}

\appendix
\chapter{Appendix Title}
\input{chapters/appendix}
\singlespacing
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

I attempted to separate `\listoftables` &  `\listoffigures` as their own individual .tex files into the `main.tex` file itself. This did not work and Overleaf just recognized it as a non-preliminary chapter (i.e. like chapter 1 in the code).

The document with "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" in the header does show up in the output .pdf file following the table of contents page.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case by default as `\chapter*` - unnumbered - sectional units (included are `\tableofcontents`, `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`). If you want them included, use the following construction:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
```

The `\cleardoublepage` puts you on the correct page to start the ToC/LoF/LoT, while `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}` inserts a `chapter`-like element in the ToC (the `.toc` file).

All of the above is supplied by default when using the [`tocbibind` package](//ctan.org/pkg/tocbibind).